# How to fetch particular record from XML dataset based on dropdown selection in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, xml

XML FILE:

ss.xml

There are 12k records in xml file

```
<record id="R1">
<Imgpath>GR8138K-SS.jpg</Imgpath>
<Exclusives> </Exclusives> 
<Collection> </Collection>
<ProductCategory>Mens Ring</ProductCategory>
<SubCategory>Left Hand Mens Ring</SubCategory>
<Attribute2>3 Row Band</Attribute2>
<DiamondWeightRange>0.96 - 1.10 cts</DiamondWeightRange>
<CenterStoneWeightRange> </CenterStoneWeightRange>
<CenterShape> </CenterShape>
<SideShape> </SideShape>
<CenterSetting> </CenterSetting>
<Finishes>Satin</Finishes>
<SearchStyleNo>GR8138K-SS</SearchStyleNo> 
<Month>June</Month>
<Year>2009</Year>
<TotalWeight>1.02</TotalWeight>
<CenterStWeight> </CenterStWeight>
</record>

<record id="R2">
<Imgpath>GR8138K-SS.jpg</Imgpath>
<Exclusives> </Exclusives> 
<Collection> </Collection>
<ProductCategory>Ladies Ring</ProductCategory>
<SubCategory>Wedding Band</SubCategory>
<Attribute2> </Attribute2>
<DiamondWeightRange>0.29 - 0.35 cts</DiamondWeightRange>
<CenterStoneWeightRange> </CenterStoneWeightRange>
<CenterShape> </CenterShape>
<SideShape> </SideShape>
<CenterSetting> </CenterSetting>
<Finishes> </Finishes>
<SearchStyleNo>GMR048F-W</SearchStyleNo>
<Month>July</Month>
<Year>2008</Year>
<TotalWeight>0.3</TotalWeight>
<CenterStWeight> </CenterStWeight>
</record>

<record id="R3">
<Imgpath>GRB728K-W.JPG</Imgpath>
<Exclusives> </Exclusives> 
<Collection> </Collection>    
<ProductCategory>Mens Ring</ProductCategory>
<SubCategory>Left Hand Mens Ring</SubCategory>
<DiamondWeightRange>0.96 - 1.10 cts</DiamondWeightRange>
<CenterShape>Round</CenterShape>
<SearchStyleNo>GRB728K-W</SearchStyleNo>
<Month>August</Month>
<Year>2008</Year>
<TotalWeight>0.97</TotalWeight>
</record>

<record id="R4">
<Imgpath>GRF001D-X.jpg</Imgpath>
<ProductCategory>Mens Ring</ProductCategory>
<SubCategory>Left Hand Mens Ring</SubCategory>
<Attribute2>7 Stone Band, Combination of Metal</Attribute2>
<DiamondWeightRange>0.16 - 0.18 cts</DiamondWeightRange>
<CenterShape>Round</CenterShape>
<Finishes>Satin</Finishes>
<SearchStyleNo>GRF001D-X</SearchStyleNo>
<Month>September</Month>
<Year>2008</Year>
<TotalWeight>0.18</TotalWeight>
</record>
```

JavaScript:

To load xml data

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
              xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
          else {
              xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
          async: false
          xhttp.open("GET", dname, false);
          xhttp.send();
          return xhttp.responseXML;
      }
      $(document).ready(function () {

          try {
              xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("ss.xml");
              x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("record");


              //For every element, loop

              var col = 4;

              var total = x.length;

              var row = Math.ceil(x.length / 4);

              var table = $('<table></table>');

              for (r = 0; r <= row; r++) {
                  var rowtr = $('<tr></tr>');

                  var t = 0;
                  if (r == 0) {
                      t == r;
                  }
                  else {
                      var t = (r * 4) + 1;
                  }
                  if (total - t >= col) {
                      col = 4;
                  }
                  else {
                      col = total - t;

                  }
                  for (c = 0; c < col; c++) {

                      var imgpath = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Imgpath")[t].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                      var exc = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Exclusives")[t].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                      var coll = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Collection")[t].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                     // alert(coll);

                      var Pcat = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ProductCategory")[t].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                      var Scat = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SubCategory")[t].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                      var Att = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Attribute2")[t].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                      var DiaWtRange = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DiamondWeightRange")[t].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                      var CenStoneRange = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CenterStoneWeightRange")[t].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                      var CenShape = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CenterShape")[t].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                      var SShape = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SideShape")[t].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                      var CenSetting = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CenterSetting")[t].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                      var Fin = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Finishes")[t].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                      var SSNo = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SearchStyleNo")[t].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                      var Mon = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Month")[t].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                      var Yr = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Year")[t].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                      var TotWeight = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("TotalWeight")[t].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                      var CenStWeight = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CenterStWeight")[t].childNodes[0].nodeValue;


                     rowtr.append('<td><img src="' + imgpath + '" height="200px" width="200px" class="zoom_img"/><br/> Style No:  ' + SSNo + '<br/> Product: ' + Pcat + '<br/> Category: ' + Scat + '<br/> Center stone weight: ' + CenStWeight + '<br/> Total weight: ' + TotWeight + '<br/>' + '<input type="button" value="Add to Selection" style="border-radius: 5px;" onclick="' + AddtoCart(imgpath, exc, coll, Pcat, Scat, Att, DiaWtRange, CenStoneRange, CenShape, SShape, CenSetting, Fin, SSNo, Mon, Yr, TotWeight, CenStWeight) + '"class="cart"/>  </td>');


                      t = t + 1;
                  };
                  table.append(rowtr);

              };
              $('#dvContent').append(table);
          } catch (e) {
              alert(e.message);

          }

      });
</script>
```

Html :

Here is dropdown shape.

when we select value "Oval", it filters xml dataset and display those record having center shape "Oval". similarly for other filters.

simply filters the record based on particular tagname.

```
        <select class="form-control" id="DdlCshape">
          <option value="">       Select  Center Shape    </option>
          <option value="Baguette"> Baguette    </option>
          <option value="Cushion">  Cushion      </option>
          <option value="Emerald">  Emerald     </option>
          <option value="Marquise"> Marquise    </option>
          <option value="Oval">     Oval        </option>
          <option value="Pear">     Pear        </option>
          <option value="Princess"> Princess        </option>
          <option value="Radiant">  Radiant     </option>
          <option value="Round">    Round       </option>
          <option value="Tapper">   Tapper      </option>
        </select>
        <select class="form-control" id="DdlCSWeight>
          <option value="">Select Center Stone Weight Range </option>
          <option value="0.01 - 0.05 cts">0.01 - 0.05 cts</option>
          <option value="0.11 - 0.15 cts">0.11 - 0.15 cts</option>
          <option value="0.19 - 0.22 cts">0.19 - 0.22 cts</option>
          <option value="0.23 - 0.28 cts">0.23 - 0.28 cts</option>
          <option value="0.29 - 0.35 cts">0.29 - 0.35 cts</option>
          <option value="0.36 - 0.45 cts">0.36 - 0.45 cts</option>
          <option value="0.46 - 0.55 cts">0.46 - 0.55 cts</option>
          <option value="0.56 - 0.65 cts">0.56 - 0.65 cts</option>
          <option value="0.66 - 0.78 cts">0.66 - 0.78 cts</option>
          <option value="0.96 - 1.10 cts">0.96 - 1.10 cts</option>
        </select>
        <select class="form-control" id="DdlWeight_Range">
          <option value=""> Select Diamond Weight Range </option>
          <option value="0.01 - 0.05 cts">0.01 - 0.05 cts</option>
          <option value="0.11 - 0.15 cts">0.11 - 0.15 cts</option>
          <option value="0.19 - 0.22 cts">0.19 - 0.22 cts</option>
          <option value="0.23 - 0.28 cts">0.23 - 0.28 cts</option>
          <option value="0.29 - 0.35 cts">0.29 - 0.35 cts</option>
          <option value="0.36 - 0.45 cts">0.36 - 0.45 cts</option>
          <option value="0.46 - 0.55 cts">0.46 - 0.55 cts</option>
          <option value="0.56 - 0.65 cts">0.56 - 0.65 cts</option>
          <option value="0.66 - 0.78 cts">0.66 - 0.78 cts</option>
          <option value="0.96 - 1.10 cts">0.96 - 1.10 cts</option>
          <option value="1.11 - 1.78 cts">1.11 - 1.78 cts</option>
          <option value="1.79 - 2.10 cts">1.79 - 2.10 cts</option>
          <option value="2.29 - 2.78 cts">2.29 - 2.78 cts</option>
        </select>
```